# How to get push notification in a mobile App (React Native or Ionic) using Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, react-native

I'm trying to create a push notification in React-Native using a Spring Boot server and a MySQL database.

I would like to know how to set up my Spring Boot Rest API to be able to send push notification to a front-end coded with React-Native. Is there any technology that I can use to achieve that ? Or how to code it in Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google's firebase push notifications (FCM) to achieve the same.

Go through the below articles it has given all the information for spring boot as backend and front end as react native,

https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/firebase-cloud-messaging-server-spring-to-push-notification-example-spring-boot

https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591